# How to return NULL for Identity when no INSERT is performed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_1 
( 
ID Int IDENTITY(1,1), 
Name Varchar(500) 
) 

CREATE TABLE Temp_2 
( 
 ID Int IDENTITY(1,1), 
 Name Varchar(500) 
  ) 


  INSERT INTO Temp_1 
  SELECT 'CC' 

  INSERT INTO Temp_2 
  SELECT Name 
  FROM Temp_1 
  WHERE 2 = 1
```

There is no insertion into the table Temp_2.So my expected output for the SCOPE_IDENTITY () for the table Temp_2 is NULL.

**How can i get the Identity Value of the Temp_2 as null?**

If we use the SCOPE_IDENTITY() OR @@IDENTITY, the identity value we are getting is only of the table Temp_1. We need to get the identity value of table Temp_2 which is "null" as there is no insertion in the table Temp_2 .

Answer (score 4):

Neither.  You want to use the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause:

```
  DECLARE @ids TABLE (id INT);

  INSERT INTO Temp_1 
      OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @ids
      SELECT 'CC' ;
```

This is session-safe, statement-safe, multi-threaded safe.  And it allows you to handle multiple row inserts.  And it allows you to return additional columns.

There is no reason to use any other method.